# Relative path in Struts2 and OpenCSVWriter

Tags: java, struts2, netbeans-7, opencsv

I have a file that is stored in my netbeans project in the following path:

```
ReportCSV/ReportDownload.csv
```

And I have the following code in my struts action class to write to this file:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\isis\\src\\main\\webapp\\ReportCSV\\ReportDownload.csv"), '\t');

//feed in your array (or convert your data to an array)
String[] entries = "first#second#third".split("#");
writer.writeNext(entries);
writer.close();
```

Over here, specifying the exact file path works but I would like to make this path relative. I've tried `"\\ReportCSV\\ReportDownload.csv"` but it doesn't work. Any idea what I can do?
Any help is appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: A relative path doesn't start with backslash. It starts with the name of a relative file or directory (for example: `ReportDownload.csv` or `foo/bar/ReportDownload.csv`). Also, be aware that it will be relative to the current directory of the JVM, i.e. to the directory from which java was executed. This is probably NOT what you want in a webapp, so you'd better use an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Will take this into account!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a relative path to your application web, you need `javax.servlet.ServletContext`.

With the class [`org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/ServletActionContext.html), you can try:

```
ServletContext context = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
String path = context.getRealPath("/ReportCSV/ReportDownload.csv");
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(path), '\t');
```

Comment: @t_lo: be aware that as soon as you redeploy your webapp, you'l lose your saved documents. Just as you shouldn't store your documlents in c:\program files, you shouldn't store them in the webapp's installation directory.